# Error al cargar stactic files con django

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, cache

Estoy empezando a hacer programación web con Python y Django y se me ha presentado el siguiente inconveniente: se hicieron unos cambios en unos JS y CSS pero estos no se estaban visualizando al acceder a la página; por lo tanto buscando una solución se limpió caché y se ejecutaron [las instrucciones que recomendaba este post del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720596/django-web-application-and-ways-to-flush-cached-media/31037800#31037800):

```
python3 manage.py clear_cache 
python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
python3 manage.py compress --force
```

Luego ya el sitio no carga los JS ni los CSS, generando error 404. Ya se revisó el settings.py y no se alteró el archivo. Agradezco la ayuda, no sé si es que después de ejecutar los comandos debo hacer alguna tarea manual, como copiar o mover de nuevo los archivos.

Comment: Hola Viviana, bienvenida a StackOverflow, ¿Que has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Que problemas has tenido? Te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio para entender como funcionamos aquí y de paso ganar tu primera medalla, a su vez, te recomiendo pasar por [ask] para ver como elaborar una buena pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida, por favor, considera también invertir algo de tu tiempo en realizar un [mcve] , un saludo.

Comment: Aritzbn muchas gracias por las recomendaciones las tendré en cuenta

Answer (score -1):

si la variable `BASE_DIR` en el archivo **settings.py** 
tiene este valor

```
 os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

es decir

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

entonces, usa agrega esto:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_dev'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_dev')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

y luego al llamar en el html a los archivos **js**, **css**:

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "ruta al archivo/css.css" %}">
< script type="text/javascript" src=" {% static "ruta al archivo/js.js" %}"></script>
```

y en el directorio raiz del proyecto agrega una carpeta llamada "static_dev" y dentro de ella entonces guardaras los archivos css, js, imagenes y demas.
Espero te sirva, saludos y bienvenida a StackOverflow

Comment: ah se me olvidaba al inicio del html debes poner <code>{% load static %}</code>

Answer (score -1):

Si te falta los archivos js o css, tienes que agregar el sgte código. a tus

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
REPOSITORY_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'media/')
```

Luego en la url.py del proyecto:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
....urls......
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```